# define a named variable in a function call

Tags: c++, function, vector, reference, parameter-passing

What is the problem int the code?
I've got:

> "error: expected primary-expression before 'j'"

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void foo(vector<int>& v){  
}

int main()
{
   foo( vector<int> j);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller Such comments are best accompanied with a link to SO's [list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid:

```
foo( vector<int> j);
```

because you just can NOT define a named variable in a function call....

you mean for sure

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> j;
    foo(j);
    return 0;
}
```